# How to change the date and time in linode server

Tags: linode

I want to change the date and time in linode server which should give me my preferred time and date.

sudo date --set = "2018-08-06 11:05:00"

```
sudo date --set = "2018-08-06 11:05:00"
```

The above command I'm giving but once I gave command like date it showing the current time and date not my preferred date and time

Answer (score 0):

access terminal and type following command;
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
 time zone info is saved in /etc/timezone
which can be edited
$ echo "Australia/Adelaide" | sudo tee /etc/timezone
Asutralia/Adelaide
$sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata

then proceed with the time configuration of your time zone.
you will see clock and time zone here in terminal as well.
thanks,
Syeda